# PHP code for blacklisting and rewriting/redirecting URLs

Tags: php, url-routing, joomla

We faced an issue where URLs had a wrong "subfolder" in its URL, so e.g.

```
example.com/match1/randomgenerated
```

should have been

```
example.com/rewritewiththis/randomgenerated
```

We currently use this code for redirecting URLs that (maybe it could be that it only starts at urls that are "bad"):

```
$oldurl = JUri::getInstance();
$newurl = str_replace(['match1','match2','match3'], 'rewritewiththis', $oldurl);

$bad_urls = array('match1','match2','match3');

foreach($bad_urls as $bad_url){
    if(strpos($oldurl, $bad_url) !== false) {
        exit(header("Location: $newurl", true, 301));
    }
}
```

We use the `$newurl` also for things like this (this rewrites the generated URLs to use a correct URL and prevent duplicate content):

```
$oldurl = $this->getRoute($event->url_query . '&Itemid=' . $request->query->page_id)->toString();
$data['url'] = str_replace('match1', 'rewritewiththis', $oldurl);
```

Are there better options to do this are are is this already a good way to solve this issue?

Comment: If this is a Joomla script, you might like to ask at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange -- where folks with intimate knowledge about the CMS can tell you about pre-scripted functionalities and best practices within the CMS.

Comment: @mickmackusa yes, this was about Joomla. The issue here is that we don't have such a deep knowledge of the component, as we didn't program it fully. The URL generation is one of this, that we didn't change. But thanks for the link to the Joomla Stack Exchange. :)

Comment: We have some pretty smart cookies over there.  I recommend a cross post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it looks good, a little verbose. Could be simplified to this

```
$oldurl = JUri::getInstance();
$bad_urls = ['match1','match2','match3'];
$newurl = str_replace($bad_urls, 'rewritewiththis', $oldurl);

if(in_array($oldurl, $bad_urls))
    exit(header("Location: $newurl", true, 301));
```

If you need to use something like this in many locations, or you need to elaborate on what are considered bad urls a router system/class may be a better way to go.

If you're asking if there's a different way to re-route without using `header()` I don't think there is. Any router system I have seen uses `header()` to re-route, no matter how much code surrounds and abstracts them.